# Laravel - how can make dynamic content with layout?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm wanting to create a website with laravel framework. I had made layout but now, have some zone i don't know how to set content for it. Ex: 2 zone of me are left-menu and cart (please view picture). My left-menu will get content from table: categories and cart will get content from package cart [Cart::content()].
It's on layout and of course, all page will have it. But i don't know how to give content of categories and cart() for it. Please help me
[image: left-menu and cart]

Comment: Post the code that you've tried and doesn't work and we might be able to help you. Refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should to use View Composer.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

Use Blade templates, as found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade

Wherever in your page you want to print content, use the {{ $mycontent }} construct. You can also use confitionals and loop structures like @if and @foreach to loop through collections.

Then, in your controllers, you can just call the view and pass it content from your database or wherever you get it by doing something like:

return response()->view(“myView”, [“mycontent” => $content], $httpStatus);

Answer (score 0):

You may opt for [afterMiddleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware) if you want it on every page. Create a section on the master blade page (usually app.blade.php) and fill it in the middleware just like you would in any other controller. You can create a middleware by running `php artisan create:middleware Cart`. A file will be created at `app/Http/Middleware/Cart.php`.

Register the middleware in the `app/Http/kernel.php` file.

You may have to add a `Auth::check()` condition to avoid errors.